# Expensive query on database side

Tags: sql, rdbms

Let's consider this two tables:

```
|     Person    |
----------------
|  ID  | Name   | 
_________________
|  1   |  alice |
|  2   |  bob   |  
|  ... |  ...   |  
| 99   |  zach  |  


| PersonFriend  |
----------------
|  ID  |FriendID| 
_________________
|  1   |  2     |
|  2   |  1     |  
|  2   |  99    |
| ...  |  ...   |  
| 99   |  1     |
```

These are two tables to model friends and friends-of-friends.
Now the first query is:
1) *Who are Bob’s friends?*
The query using SQL is:

```
SELECT p1.Person
FROM Person p1 JOIN PersonFriend  ON PersonFriend.FriendID = p1.ID 
     JOIN Person p2  ON PersonFriend.PersonID = p2.ID 
WHERE p2.Person = 'bob'
```

Now consider the viceversa:
2) *Who is friends with Bob?*
The query in SQL is:

```
SELECT p1.Person 
FROM Person p1 JOIN PersonFriend  ON PersonFriend.PersonID = p1.ID 
     JOIN Person p2  ON PersonFriend.FriendID = p2.ID 
WHERE p2.Person = 'bob'
```

Well, these two queries are both easy, but I don't understand why the second one is  more expensive on the database side than the first. Can someone help me?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: It is useful to know indexes, keys and data size. How do you define expensive?

Comment: By expansive you mean estimated query cost by execution plan or just a hunch?

Comment: I think it's not important the type of RDBMS. 
No indexes defined. 
The subject is the different between RDBMS and graphDB(NoSQL) in a highly connected domains

Comment: @DistribuzioneGaussiana . . . With the right indexes and table structures, both queries should have similar performance.  If you are going to compare unoptimized RDBMS to NOSQL, then don't both.  The optimized solution will work better and you can save time with just choosing the tool that you are biased towards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to reply on my own. 
Let's consider the query tree of the two queries:

1) Who are Bob’s friends?

```
   PROJ p1.Person
          |
          |
     J   O   I   N 
 p1.ID=PersonFriend.FriendID 
     /            \
    /              \
   /                \
Person p1    ###### J   O   I   N ######
              p2.ID=PersonFriend.PersonID 
                      /         \
                     /           \ 
                    /             \ 
                SEL(Persona p2)   PersonFriend
           p2.Person="bob"
```

2) Who is friends with Bob?

```
     PROJ p1.Person
              |
              |
         J   O   I   N 
     p1.ID=PersonFriend.PersonID 
         /            \
        /              \
       /                \
    Person p1    ###### J   O   I   N ######
                  p2.ID=PersonFriend.FriendID  
                          /         \
                         /           \ 
                        /             \ 
                    SEL(Persona p2)   PersonFriend
               p2.Person="bob"
```

The key of PersonFriend table is compound: , and records are sorted by ID.
As you can see the two joins marked by hashes have differents arguments. The first one does not need to iterate all records of PersonFriend table, because records are sorted by ID. The second join, needs to iterate all records of PersonFriend table.
 *I think this is the reason why the second query is more expensive than the first.*

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing this example quoted in the Neo4j graph database book and think it is a highly contrived example. In the example mentioned, there will be no performance hit.

As they explain later in the book, only more complex queries like friend-of-friends are computationally expensive.

Example 2-3. Alice’s friends-of-friends

```
SELECT p1.Person AS PERSON, p2.Person AS FRIEND_OF_FRIEND
FROM PersonFriend pf1 JOIN Person p1
ON pf1.PersonID = p1.ID
JOIN PersonFriend pf2
ON pf2.PersonID = pf1.FriendID
JOIN Person p2
ON pf2.FriendID = p2.ID
WHERE p1.Person = 'Alice' AND pf2.FriendID <> p1.ID
```

Comment: Yeah this is an example cames from Neo4j graph database book.